# Индиец и индус

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Слышала такое, что индиец - это национальность, а индус - вероисповедание (человек, исповедующий индуизм). Правда ли это, или оба слова - синонимы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Индиец - житель Индии.
Индус
1. последователь индуизма
2. то же, что индиец (устаревшее).