# "Индус" — употребляется ли слово и что под ним понимают?

Tags: значение-слов

Был давно об этом [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%86-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%81/4654#4654), но там ответ очень краткий. Написано, что *индус* в значении *индиец* устаревшее. Это правда? Сейчас так не говорят?!

В то же время написано, что это последователь индуизма. Получается, русского индуиста можно назвать *индусом?*

Comment: "Сейчас так не говорят?!" - в контексте индустрии  разработки софта только так и говорят, и их вероисповедание никого не интересует.

Comment: Спасибо, интересно. :)

Comment: Но это АйТи-шный жаргон, не лит.норма.